# Set Hardware Breakpoint to multiple addresses in one thread

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, hardware, breakpoints

I'm trying to set up hardware breakpoint for 2 addresses at 1 time for 1 thread but in this example works only DR0. If I enable only DR0 or only DR1 it works correctly

I'm trying:

```
ctx.Dr0 = address1;
ctx.Dr1 = address2;

int SevenFlags = ctx.Dr7;
SevenFlags |= (1 << 0); //enabling DR0
SevenFlags |= (1 << 2); //enabling DR1
ctx.Dr7 = SevenFlags;

ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This lacks context. Like what environment are you working in? What does it mean it doesn't not work?

Comment: Only DR0 works when DR1 enabled too. Visual studio, Windows

Comment: Please edit that info into the question, and add appropriate tags.

Comment: There are flags in the upper bits of DR7 indicating the conditions (read / write / execute) and size for each hardware breakpoint.  You need to initialize those too since they might be set to something unexpected.

Comment: I solved it by setting second address to DR3 bit instead of DR1/DR2. Not sure why it even works now. P.S. I checked higher bits. They are fine